# select rows with non distinct values in column 1 scoped to column 2

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql

So i have a people table and bank_accounts table:

```
People
id | name
1    John
2    Mark
3    Mary

BankAccount
id | person_id | currency
1      1          'USD'
2      1          'EUR'
3      2          'USD'
4      2          'USD'
5      3          'EUR'
```

I want to get back all accounts with their owners if that owner has only accounts with max one kind of currency. I don't want to get back **any** account which is owned by user which has another account in another currency. erm :P

so the table i want to get back looks like that:

```
account_id | person_id | currency

3            2(Mark)     'USD'
4            2(Mark)     'USD'
5            3(Mary)     'EUR'
```

Hope it's understandable. This is simplified example of course. I will use this on a lot bigger tables with a lot of data. So some efficiency would be also good.

Thanks a lot for your time and help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * 
from bankAccount
where person_id in
(
  select person_id
  from bankAccount
  group by person_id
  having count(distinct currency) = 1
)
```

Comment: While this post may answer the question, it is still a good idea to add some explanation and, possibly, some links to the relevant documentation. Answers with good explanations and references are usually more useful both to the current OP and to the future visitors. Full detailed answers are also more likely to attract positive votes.